# Kivy Buildozer mergeExtDexDebug FAILED

Tags: android, kivy, apk, buildozer, p4a

I'm trying to compile an apk but when nearly done this happens.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform guice-5.1.0.jar (com.google.inject:guice:5.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c608519f0d9339c5924abc1c109a4d/transformed/jetified-guice-5.1.0.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

Already tried changing /content/buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/skyguard/build.gradle minSDK from 24 to 26 but that didn't fix it. I'd really appreciate any help because I can't find anything.